# Routing outgoing traffic from multiple VPCs across different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have internet gateways attached to multiple VPCs (around 5 and likely to grow) and I currently do not have NAT gateways for outbound traffic. My third party service providers have a limitation to white-list only 2 to 3 IP addresses. Even if I add NAT gateways to each VPC, I will still have too many IP addresses to be whitelisted. So how do make sure that all current outgoing traffic from existing VPCs (in multiple regions and accounts) get routed via a single (or max 2) IPs?